# Azure Data Factory Jobs Failing in Hadoop/Map Reduce?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Some of my ADF jobs are randomly failing, with the output directed in data in the /PackageJobs/~job/Status/stderr file below.

Note that this doesn't always happen, it occurs randomly on some of the jobs, and others complete normally.

What can be causing this problem?

The stderr data is as follows:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class     [com.microsoft.log4jappender.FilterLogAppender].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.log4jappender.FilterLogAppender
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:327)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:124)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:785)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:672)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:516)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:262)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:108)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1025)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:844)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:541)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:292)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:269)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:657)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.<clinit>(ShutdownHookManager.java:44)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:200)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "RMSUMFilterLog".
16/03/04 10:56:02 INFO impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address: http://headnodehost:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
16/03/04 10:56:02 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at headnodehost/100.74.24.3:9010
16/03/04 10:56:02 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at headnodehost/100.74.24.3:10200
16/03/04 10:56:03 INFO impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address: http://headnodehost:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
16/03/04 10:56:03 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at headnodehost/100.74.24.3:9010
16/03/04 10:56:03 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at headnodehost/100.74.24.3:10200
16/03/04 10:56:06 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/03/04 10:56:06 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
16/03/04 10:56:06 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduces
16/03/04 10:56:06 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
16/03/04 10:56:07 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1457068773628_0022
16/03/04 10:56:07 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Kind: mapreduce.job, Service: job_1457068773628_0019, Ident: (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.token.JobTokenIdentifier@655019bc)
16/03/04 10:56:08 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1457068773628_0022
16/03/04 10:56:08 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://headnodehost:9014/proxy/application_1457068773628_0022/
16/03/04 10:56:08 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1457068773628_0022
16/03/04 10:56:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1457068773628_0022 running in uber mode : false
16/03/04 10:56:18 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/03/04 10:56:31 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/03/04 23:48:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1457068773628_0022_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
AttemptID:attempt_1457068773628_0022_m_000000_0 Timed out after 600 secs
16/03/04 23:49:00 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/03/04 23:49:16 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/03/05 00:01:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1457068773628_0022_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
AttemptID:attempt_1457068773628_0022_m_000000_1 Timed out after 600 secs
16/03/05 00:01:01 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/03/05 00:01:21 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/03/05 00:13:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1457068773628_0022_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
AttemptID:attempt_1457068773628_0022_m_000000_2 Timed out after 600 secs
16/03/05 00:13:01 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/03/05 00:13:18 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/03/05 00:25:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1457068773628_0022 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1457068773628_0022_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

16/03/05 00:25:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 9
Job Counters 
    Failed map tasks=4
    Launched map tasks=4
    Other local map tasks=3
    Rack-local map tasks=1
    Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=48514665
    Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
    Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=48514665
    Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=48514665
    Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=74518525440
16/03/05 00:25:03 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful!
Streaming Command Failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the known timeout issue with Hadoop/HDI. If an activity doesn’t write anything on the console for 10 mins, then it gets killed. Can you please modify your code to write a ping on console every 9 minutes and see if it works

Comment: I did not face this issue again, though I never made any changes to the activity, might have been an internal issue.